# What happens to the electric field lines in a high resistance conductor?

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors, vector-fields

When a conductor is connected to a potential difference, an electric field occurs inside the conductor. We know in a high resistance conductor (for example a 20m long thin carbon rod connected to a 1.5 V battery)  the magnitude of the electric field decreases as we go further in the conductor.  And, when the electric field decreases the distance between the field lines increase.

So, is the following picture I made correct? Does the field lines emerge out of the conductor as shown in the picture? If not how do you represent the reducing electric field?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that "the magnitude of the electric field decreases as we go further in the conductor."? If we're talking about a steady-state condition, then if there is a field in the conductor, there will be a current flowing through it. This can't happen unless the other end of the conductor is connected to something that can supply the electrons that make up the current. If the other end isn't connected to something that can supply current, then the charges of the conductor will rearrange to form a surface charge that negates any field within the conductor.

Comment: @ThePhoton what if the voltage of negetive terminal was grounded ( If it has 0 V ). Then would the above diagram be accurate.

Comment: this is a conductive material, therefore current will flow in the direction of the electric field lines according to $\vec{j}=\sigma\vec{E}$. If there's no way for current to flow out the sides of the conductor, then we know there won't be field lines pointing out the sides of the conductor. There's no reason field lines can't terminate on a grounded object or surface (actually that's a very common scenario).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how the field decreases as you go in the conductor. If you are talking about skin depth, this is true only for varying fields. In the case of an ohmic resistor, $\vec j$ is proportional to $\vec E$ so according to your digram, current is leaking from the sides of your conductor. For the correct distribution of the electric field, it will depend on the shape of your electrodes at the end, but if they are flat and perpendicular to the length of your conductor, the electric field is uniform inside due to the imposed boundary conditions (check out Griffith's Introduction to Electrodynamics).

If your conductor has weird quantum properties, then of course this simple classical point of view will fall apart, but you need to specify it.
Hope this helps and tell me if you find some mistakes.

Comment: sorry for the lack of explaination. My english is not very good. Your answer seems correct.